# "Object is of type 'unknown'." in RxJS action

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a source code like below and I do not know why I got error in line 143, but in line 137 I did not got such kind of error. Any idea how to make sure TypeScript that the type in line 143 is OK? Maybe should I add some type, if so where?

[image]

I Insert also source code as a plain text:

```
exhaustMap(action =>
  // call asyncProcess() and delay until promise is fulfilled
  components
    .deleteComponent(action.payload.id, action.payload.projects, action.payload.useCases)
    .pipe(
      // map promise result to success action
      mergeMap(() => {
        filterAction(deleteComponentAction.request),
        mergeMap(action =>
          components.deleteComponent(action.payload.id).pipe(
            mergeMap(() => of(deleteComponentAction.success(), fetchCategoryComponentList.request({category: "gateway"}))),
            catchError((error: Error) => of(deleteComponentAction.failure(errorHandler(error))))
          )
        )
      }),
```

Comment: the project function of mergeMap needs at least one argument: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap , so try `mergeMap(x =>{`

Comment: I tried it but does not work. ;-(

Comment: OK. So what type is `action`?

Comment: what does `deleteComponent()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lays in row 140. There you place a `mergeMap` operator and you pass to it a function in the form of `() => {// do stuff}`. The key point here is that you are using curly braces in the definition of the body of this function.

The function passed to `mergeMap` has to return an Observable and the fact that you are using curly braces requires you to use an explicit `return` to define the returned value. But if I look at the body of the function (rows 141-147) I do not see any `return` statement returning an Observable. This is the root cause of your error. Then I do not have a clear idea of what you want to achieve with the `mergeMap` of line 137, but, whatever you want to do, make sure you do return an Observable.

Answer (score 1):

this is a shot in the dark because i have no idea what your functions return, but try this and let me know how it goes:

```
exhaustMap(action =>
// call asyncProcess() and delay until promise is fulfilled
components
.deleteComponent(action.payload.id, action.payload.projects, action.payload.useCases)
.pipe(
  // map promise result to success action
  mergeMap((deleteComponentAction: CorrectTypeHere) => {
    filterAction(deleteComponentAction.request),
    mergeMap((filterAction: CorrectTypeHere )=>
      components.deleteComponent(filterAction.payload.id).pipe(
        mergeMap((deleteComponentAction: CorrectTypeHere) => of(deleteComponentAction.success(), fetchCategoryComponentList.request({category: "gateway"}))),
        catchError((error: Error) => of(deleteComponentAction.failure(errorHandler(error))))
      )
    )
  }),
```